# Use same argument several times in python

Tags: python

I want to add argument to the argumentParser so that I can use it several times (with some values) not as sequence.
Let's say I have an optional argument '-l' that takes str value then I want to be able to run somthing like this (with python):

```
python myProg.py -l hay -l how -l are -l you
```

I used nargs in the add_argument method but it works only like that:

```
python myProg.py -l hey how are you
```

I'd like to get some help, thanks.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Not an option to do something like this? python myProg.py -l hay,how,are,you then split the input?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `action='append'`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Note that in this solution if a flag would cause an index error (i.e. `py example.py -l`), then it will be ignored instead.

```
import sys

text_positions = [i+1 for i, flag in enumerate(sys.argv) if flag == "-l"]
text = [sys.argv[text_position] for text_position in text_positions if text_position < len(sys.argv)]
# in case you want the arguments joined together as a string
text_as_string = " ".join(text)

print(text)
print(text_as_string)
```

Executing the code above produces the following result:

```
$ py example.py -l hey -l how -l are -l you
['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you']
hey how are you
```